# Accessing Global Objects from Service via Application

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

## Problem Description

I'm writing application which is based on Android `Service`. In application some of Objects (ex. Navigator) I'm initialising in `Application` class, so I can have access to then from everywhere and they are kind of Singletons.

#### CustomApplication.java

```
public class CustomApplication extends android.app.Application {

    private Navigator navigator;

    public Navigator getNavigator() {
        return this.navigator;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.navigator = new Navigator();
    }
}
```

#### CustomService.java

```
public class CustomService extends Service {

    private Navigator navigator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.navigator = ((CustomApplication)getApplication()).getNavigator();
    }
}
```

## Question

I have some doubts that calling

`this.navigator = ((CustomApplication)getApplication()).getNavigator();`

from Service `onCreate()` and in general from any method is not correct, *as in cases when application in killed and service is running it can cause some issues (ex. nullpointer)*, Am I right or it's safe to do that and it will not cause any issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as in cases when application in killed

An "application" is not "killed". Processes are terminated. If your code is running, your process is not terminated. `getApplication()` will work when your process is running.

That being said, there is no value in using a custom `Application` here, versus a standard Java singleton.